# Class Method NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, abstract

I have an

```
public abstract class Entity {

    public Entity() {}

    public void update() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
}
```

then I have a

```
public class Player Extends Entity { /* Class Definition */ }
```

when i call player.update

I get a NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainFrame.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:29)
    at Start.main(Start.java:13)
```

Comment: Have you instantiated the `player` object?

Comment: Please show us what `Gui.java` has eaten. Also note down what's on line 29 of the file `Gui.java`, since that's where the exception is thrown from.

Comment: why this class is abstract

Comment: From the stacktrace it seems like it has nothing (so far) to do with these classes. Could you please post the lines mentioned in the stacktrace? (Start : 13 and Gui : 29,  preferably with the surrounding code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gui.java on line 29 your **player** variable is pointing to null, 
i.e. it is not initialized. So you get the exception that you get.
The solution is to make sure **player** is not null before using it.

And you can do that by calling some constructor i.e. by doing something like

```
Player player = new Player(); // call some constructor here
```

Do that before calling any methods on **player** and you should be good.

Comment: I thought I initialized in the array but I had not.  Whoops, thanks